# Copy & Convert Data from Worksheet A to Worksheet B

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to both copy and convert data from 1 sheet to another. Currently my team has to use 3 different sheets just for the purpose of getting clean data.

To be more specific, 
1st: Raw data is first pasted into a sheet called "Paste Target Data Here".
2nd: From there, the "Converted" sheet which has Excel formulas in each column would take value from PTDH sheet and convert the data into some specific values (depending on the function used in each column)
3rd: Now, my team would have to copy and paste as value everything on "Converted" sheet to "Master Worksheet" which shares the exact column order with "Converted".

I believe this long procedure can be reduced to just 2 tabs/sheets and bypass the "Converted" part: one to paste Raw data, another to convert and get the final, clean data.

Here is what I currently have in my Module:

```
Sub UpdateMaster()
Dim r As Range
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wsSAP as Worksheet
Dim LastR As Integer

If MsgBox("Update data from 'SAP' to 'Master Worksheet'?", _
vbYesNo + vbQuestion +vbDefaultButton2, "Update Master") = vbNo Then
   Exit Sub
End If

Set wsMaster = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Master Worksheet")
Set wsSAP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP")

LastR = wsSAP.Columns("J:J, X:X, AA:AD, AI:AM, AP:AP, AY:AY").Find(What:="*",_
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

'Turn Off Events
   Application.EnableEvents = False
'Get rid of old data
   wsMaster.Cells.ClearContents
'Copy Columns from SAP to Master
   wsSAP.Range("AY2:AY" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("A2")
   wsSAP.Range("C2:C" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("B2")
   'Code for Column C here - use If statement
   wsSAP.Range("AB2:AB" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("D2")
   wsSAP.Range("AA2:AA" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("E2")
   wsSAP.Range("AC2:AC" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("F2")
   wsSAP.Range("AD2:AD" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("G2")
   wsSAP.Range("AI2:AI" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("H2")
   wsSAP.Range("AJ2:AJ" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("I2")
   wsSAP.Range("AK2:AK" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("J2")
   wsSAP.Range("AL2:AL" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("K2")
   wsSAP.Range("AP2:AP" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("L2")
   'Code for Column M here - use If statement
   'Code for Column AU here - use If statement
   'Code for Column AV here - use If statement
   'Code for Column AW here - use If statement
   'Code for Column AX here - use If statement


'Add formulas
 Set r = wsMaster.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(17)
 Set r = r.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1, r.Columns.Count)
 r.Formula = "=IF(AND(N2=""Podding"", O2=""Rollup""),""Podding"",IF(O2=N2,""Sales/Production"",IF(P2=O2,""Production"",IF(P2=N2,""Sales"",""""))))"

 Set r = wsMaster.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(21)
 Set r = r.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1, r.Columns.Count)
 r.Formula = "=IF(AND(R2=""Podding"", S2=""Rollup""),""Podding"",IF(AND(R2=""Shipped"", S2=""Rollup""),""Sales/Production"",IF(R2=S2,""Sales/Production"",IF(S2=T2,""Production"",IF(R2=T2,""Sales"","""")))))"

 Set r = wsMaster.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(25)
 Set r = r.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1, r.Columns.Count)
 r.Formula = "=IF(AND(V2=""Podding"", W2=""Rollup""),""Podding"",IF(AND(V2=""Shipped"", W2=""Rollup""),""Sales/Production"",IF(V2=W2,""Sales/Production"",IF(W2=X2,""Production"",IF(V2=X2,""Sales"","""")))))"

 Set r = wsMaster.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(29)
 Set r = r.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1, r.Columns.Count)
 r.Formula = "=IF(AND(Z2=""Podding"", AA2=""Rollup""),""Podding"",IF(AND(Z2=""Shipped"", AA2=""Rollup""),""Sales/Production"",IF(Z2=AA2,""Sales/Production"",IF(AA2=AB2,""Production"",IF(Z2=AB2,""Sales"","""")))))"

 Set r = wsMaster.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(33)
 Set r = r.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1, r.Columns.Count)
 r.Formula = "=IF(AND(AD2=""Podding"", AE2=""Rollup""),""Podding"",IF(AND(AD2=""Shipped"", AE2=""Rollup""),""Sales/Production"",IF(AD2=AE2,""Sales/Production"",IF(AE2=AF2,""Production"",IF(AD2=AF2,""Sales"","""")))))"

 Set r = wsMaster.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(37)
 Set r = r.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1, r.Columns.Count)
 r.Formula = "=IF(AND(AH2=""Podding"", AI2=""Rollup""),""Podding"",IF(AND(AH2=""Shipped"", AI2=""Rollup""),""Sales/Production"",IF(AH2=AI2,""Sales/Production"",IF(AI2=AJ2,""Production"",IF(AH2=AJ2,""Sales"","""")))))"

 Set r = wsMaster.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(41)
 Set r = r.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1, r.Columns.Count)
 r.Formula = "=IF(AND(AL2=""Podding"", AM2=""Rollup""),""Podding"",IF(AND(AL2=""Shipped"", AM2=""Rollup""),""Sales/Production"",IF(AL2=AM2,""Sales/Production"",IF(AM2=AN2,""Production"",IF(AL2=AN2,""Sales"","""")))))"

 Set r = wsMaster.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(45)
 Set r = r.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1, r.Columns.Count)
 r.Formula = "=IF(AND(AP2=""Podding"", AQ2=""Rollup""),""Podding"",IF(AND(AP2=""Shipped"", AQ2=""Rollup""),""Sales/Production"",IF(AP2=AQ2,""Sales/Production"",IF(AQ2=AR2,""Production"",IF(AP2=AR2,""Sales"","""")))))"

'Turn On Events
   Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**1) My first problem** is, for this part of codes `wsSAP.Range("AB2:AB" & LastR).Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Range("D2")`, I have many similar lines in which I wanted to copy 1 column in "SAP" to another column in "Master Worksheet". However, I realised it wasn't the best way since I know for sure column AB in "SAP" won't have empty/blank cells from first row to last row. However, that isn't the case for other columns. Some columns might have blank/empty cells somewhere within their data ranges and my LastR might take it as the last non-empty cell and stop there without copying the rest of the cells.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

**2) My second problem**, I'm having trouble incorporating the following If statements to my current codes. Especially the part whether to use Ifs in VBA or insert formula to each cell like I did in one part of my codes. Which one is better in processing time and can you please advise how I can add them to my current codes?

For the comment `'Code for Column C here - Use If Statement`, how can I convert the following formula to the appropriate VBA codes if it has faster processing time compared to inserting formulas to the cells?

```
=IF((OR('SAP'!J2="Spare", 'SAP'!J2="Pool",'SAP'!J2="FEP")), "A/M", 'SAP'!J2)
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: Your question(s) are too broad. For (1) look up finding last row/column. If you can't specify a column use `Find`.

Comment: @SJR hi, sorry if this sounds silly but would using the `Find` avoid the issue of having an empty cell in the middle of the range? Or should I use a specific range, or example, `Range("A2:A50000") which I always assume it'd take more time to process?

Comment: Using `end(xlup)` means it won't be affected by a blank in the middle of a column, it finds the last filled cell working up from the bottom. You could work out the last row for each column.

Comment: OK I just see that you are already using Find?

Comment: @SJR yes I did use `Find` but wasn't sure if empty cells would affect it. So the `LastR = wsSAP.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` would be better in this case where I need to change the "1" to each column number?

Comment: Yes, if you want a separate value for each column.

Comment: Do your columns have the same last row? If not, do you need the last row for each column, or the one containing maximum of rows?

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi, Most of my columns share the same Last Row but some do not and some have empty cells within the range. Basically I wanted to use Last Row to make sure that everything gets copied/pasted and the processing time may be better than putting a specific range, e.g. "A2:A20000". So I guess the column that contains the maximum number of rows sounds better. But again, I don't know how to set it up to get VBA to work that way. FYI, Column AB is always the column having no empty cell within its data range and I do believe it has the maximum number of rows

Comment: @SJR thank you for your help :)

Comment: So, `wsSAP.Range("AB" & rows.Count).End(XlUp).Row` will return what you need... Or use `wsSAP.UsedRange.Rows.Count`. It will return minimum your last row...